# Error: no adapter attached in Kotlin with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an error telling me that my adapter is not attached anywhere. Yet I initialize it well in the mainActivity, so I don't understand my mistake. Nothing appears in my list.

Here is my code below (hope you see where I made a mistake thanks in advance):

MainActivity :

```js
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.rvMangaList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.rvMangaList.setHasFixedSize(true)
        getMangaData { mangas : List<Manga> ->
            binding.rvMangaList.adapter = MangaAdapter(mangas)
        }

        setContentView(binding.root)

    }

    private fun getMangaData(callback: (List<Manga>) -> Unit) {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://kitsu.io/api/edge/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val apiService = retrofit.create(WebServiceInterface::class.java)
        apiService.getListTrendingManga().enqueue(object: Callback<MangaData>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MangaData>, response: Response<MangaData>) {
                return callback(response.body()!!.mangas)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MangaData>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("ERR", t.message!!)
            }

        })
    }
}
```

My Adapter :

```js
class MangaAdapter(
    private val mangas: List<Manga>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<MangaAdapter.MangaViewHolder>(){

    class MangaViewHolder(mangaItemBinding: MangaItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mangaItemBinding.root){
        private val binding = mangaItemBinding
        fun bindManga(manga: Manga) {
            binding.mangaTitle.text = manga.titles.titleEnJp
            binding.startDate.text = manga.startDate
            //Picasso.get().load(manga.posterImage.imageTiny).into(binding.mangaImage)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MangaViewHolder {
        val mangaItemBinding = MangaItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MangaViewHolder(mangaItemBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MangaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindManga(mangas[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mangas.size
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine only when your API is returning values. And,  "No adapter attached; skipping layout" ---> you get this error when you are not receiving values from the API. Please, use your logcat to see if you are getting a proper response from api.

Answer (score 0):

move this line
`setContentView(binding.root)`
under
 `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`